# Oracle Spatial: Error with SDO_UNION

Tags: sql, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I have a table which contains address-points.

With following sql-statement i have created a 100-meter buffer around each address-point:

> CREATE TABLE BUFFERPOLYGONS AS SELECT a.OBJECTID, SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER(a.shape, m.diminfo, 100,  'unit=meter arc_tolerance=0.05') AS SHAPE
>    FROM ADDRESSPOINTS a, user_sdo_geom_metadata m 
>    WHERE a.ADDRESSPOINTS='MAINADRESS' AND m.TABLE_NAME='ADDRESSES';

After this, the created table BUFFERPOLYGONS contains a lot of circle-polygons and now I want to union them (like dissolving in ArcGIS), so I did this sql-statement:

> CREATE TABLE BUFFERPOLYGONS_DISSOLVE AS SELECT 1 AS OBJECTID, SDO_AGGR_UNION(
>     MDSYS.SDOAGGRTYPE(shape, 0.005)) AS SHAPE
>     FROM BUFFERPOLYGONS;

But after this union-statement, i get this ORA-13346 error message:

*Cause: Invalid definition of an arc. An
arc is defined using three non-collinear coordinates.
Action: Alter the definition of the arc,
or set the SDO_ETYPE or SDO_GTYPE to the line type.*

I don´t really know what I have to do now with my data (SDO_GEOMETRY)

any suggestions?

Comment: Simplify the geometries first? Using [SDO_UTIL.SIMPLIFY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_util.htm#BJEHCIBF) will also convert arcs to linestrings which might help?

Comment: What is the tolerance of the input data (ADDRESSPOINTS) ? In your query that generates the buffers, you actually use the tolerance of table ADDRESSES (not ADDRESSPOINTS). The buffer will be generated at that tolerance, but you perform the aggregation at a tolerance of 0.005 (5mm). The error probably means that, at that tolerance, some of the buffers are invalid (= contain collinear arcs). Can you show an example: just post the geometry of one of the ADDRESSPOINTS ?